# Can I copy my Mass Effect DLC from my PC to my 360?

Tags: pc, xbox-360, mass-effect-3, mass-effect-2

Hi I have all three Mass Effect games for both my PC and my Xbox 360, but only my PC has all the DLC.

I don't want to have to buy the DLC for my Xbox 360 if I don't have to so is there a way to transfer or copy it from my PC to my Xbox 360?

Answer (score 1):

No you can not transfer DLC purchased on one platform to another platform.

A couple of answers on the EA site [here](https://answers.ea.com/t5/Mass-Effect-3/DLC-transfer-from-Xbox-to-PC/td-p/4495338) and [here](https://answers.ea.com/t5/Mass-Effect-2/Mass-Effect-DLC-from-Xbox-to-PC/td-p/4065334) answer this very question.